# Finding geo and harm mean overloading

Tags: c++

I am working on a project for a class and I am having some troubles, that gave me 2 errors which i don't understand what they mean...
It gave the error: c4716 "medie" must return a value.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

float medie(float a, float b, float c)
{
    float MG,MA;
    MG= sqrt(a*b*c);
    cout<< "MG="<< MG<<endl;
    MA=(2*a*b*c)/(a+b+c);
    cout<< "MA="<< MA<<endl;

}

float medie(float a,float b,float c,float d)
{
    float MG,MA;
    MG= sqrt(a*b*c*d);
    cout<< "MG="<< MG<<endl;
    MA=(2*a*b*c*d)/(a+b+c+d);
    cout<< "MA="<< MA<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    float a,b,c,d;
    cout<<"a="<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"b="<<endl;
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"c="<<endl;
    cin>>c;
    cout<<"d="<<endl;
    cin>>d;

    medie(a,b,c);

    medie(a,b,c,d);
}
```

Comment: `medie` is defined to return float, but it's not doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `medie` function is declared to return a `float` value, but you don't have any `return` statement in it. If you declare them to return `void` the error should go away.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

void medie(float a, float b, float c)
{
    float MG,MA;
    MG = sqrt(a*b*c);
    cout<< "MG="<< MG<<endl;
    MA = (2*a*b*c)/(a+b+c);
    cout<< "MA="<< MA<<endl;

}

void medie(float a,float b,float c,float d)
{
    float MG,MA;
    MG = sqrt(a*b*c*d);
    cout<< "MG="<< MG<<endl;
    MA = (2*a*b*c*d)/(a+b+c+d);
    cout<< "MA="<< MA<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    float a,b,c,d;
    cout<<"a="<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"b="<<endl;
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"c="<<endl;
    cin>>c;
    cout<<"d="<<endl;
    cin>>d;

    medie(a,b,c);

    medie(a,b,c,d);
}
```

Comment: so what i have to do?

Comment: You can declare the function `void` instead of `float`

Comment: yeah thx for advice, but now I have another problem, the program using just the second function.

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure you only changed only the return values of both functions?

Comment: I used void instead of float

Comment: I tested the code I posted in the answer and it works just fine. [My output](https://pastebin.com/uvignf5A)

Comment: a=
5
b=
4
c=
6
d=
3
MG=10.9545
MA=16

Comment: Maybe there is some other problem with your code. Could paste your current code on pastebin.com and paste the link in comment?

Comment: That's weird. The Error message you provided suggests you are using Visual Studio as IDE. Am I right? If so, I would suggest using the debugger that comes with it. You can add breakpoint at the beginning of the main and go step by step, and check if code enters both functions.

Comment: yes i m using visual studio and i m new in this IDE, I dont know what exactly to do...

Comment: There are plenty resources online how to start with like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ebzPwixrJA). It is the easier and the faster method to find where the bug is if you code compiles, but doesn't do what you expect.